# Why does this Ajax post request fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a post request with Ajax but it doesn't work .
In the following code the first alert appears but the second ,inside the success function, doesn't appear.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

    testscore ="tryagaiDDDn"; //testvalue to enter into the mysql database
    alert("xoa"+testscore);

    $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "chatp.php",  
    data: { 'tryagain':tryagain },      
    success : function(data){  
      alert(data);
    } 
  });

    });
});
</script>
</head>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in your browser's debugging tools?  Any JavaScript errors on the browser console?  Is the HTTP request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: there are two errors :Uncaught ReferenceError: tryagain is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):21n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4 POST https://localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: If you're using Google Chrome, I recommend testing your code with the javascript console open (Shift + Ctrl + j on Windows)

Comment: error1 : Uncaught ReferenceError: tryagain is not defined

Comment: You havent defined `tryagain`. i think you have to replace `data: { 'tryagain':tryagain }, ` with `data: { 'tryagain':testscore }, `

Comment: @VitoFerrulli: Did you try defining `tryagain`?  You need to define a variable before you can use it.

Comment: @VitoFerrulli check my comment above..

Comment: ok sorry i define dte variable. Now i can see the second alert "hello" dut still 2 error : error 1 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined               errrpr 2 POST https://localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: thanks now it work but even if it work an he did correctly post and insert he show this error : POST localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED –   but it work perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  tryagain is not defined -
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
            testscore = "tryagaiDDDn"; 
            alert("xoa" + testscore);
            var tryagain = "your value"; //tryagain defined here
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "chatp.php",
                data: { 'tryagain': tryagain },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
            alert("hello");

        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks now it work but even if it work an he did correctly post and insert he show this error : POST https://localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED